# How to apply Color with Metallic Shade on 3D object's Node in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, 3d, shader, scenekit, ios12

This is the example of 3d object's node Yellow color with metallic shader.

[image]

I want to apply color to `metallic shader` for a 3d object in SceneKit via Swift.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you need – just use the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/myScene.scn")!
    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 5))

    let goldenMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    goldenMaterial.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
    goldenMaterial.metalness.contents = 1.0
    goldenMaterial.roughness.contents = 0.0
    goldenMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.95, 
                                            green: 0.75, 
                                             blue: 0.2, 
                                            alpha: 1.0)

    sphereNode.geometry?.materials = [goldenMaterial]
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

    //......................................................

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
}
```

[image]